# Does Trump's sanction on Huawei include Open Source US products, like Linux kernel & RISC-V? Does this ban effect Huawei's membership there?

Tags: united-states, china, sanctions

Trump has banned US companies from trading with Huawei.

Does this ban include US non-profit organizations, such as the [Linux Foundation](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/) and [RISC-V foundation](https://riscv.org/) ?  Huawei is a paid member of those foundations, so does this ban effect Huawei's membership in those Foundations ?

EDIT: If Huawei is barred from trading with Linux & RISC-V Foundations, then **China may have to start its own Open Source training center**. Note that Linux training and certifications are done by the US-based Linux Foundation for a fee. Another example is the [Blender training & certification program](https://www.blender.org/certification/), which is based in the Netherlands, but may lose its US trade license if it trades with Huawei.

Comment: This is a question about how a law is interpreted and applied in practice, not about the political processes which created that law. I will migrate this to Law Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that the Linux kernel is developed by thousands of contributors all over the world. It is not a “US product”. This generally applies to other open source projects as well, though the number of contributors tends to be lower.

Comment: When a business chooses an Open Source product, it chooses the whole package, including Training & Certification for it's employees.

Comment: The business does not have to get it's people certified and all that though, Neel.

Comment: Huawei does. 
It is even a Platinum Linux member & Gold RISC-V member. Would this ban effect those memberships ?

Comment: You might get an answer to the revised question at [OpenSource.SE].